# How display year month from starting of the year to one month prior to current month

Tags: unix

How to display year and month from starting of the current year to one month prior to current month.current year is 2017 and current month is 03.
I want to get the list as below.

```
201701
201702
```

If we are in April it should be

```
201701
201702
201703
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what did you try? if you are looking to write a script, say in bash, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics to get started... hint: given two variables that has year and month (as numbers), you could use the evil eval, printf and brace expansion to do it... or use arrays, etc

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to use `date +%Y%m` for different months (like GNU-date `date +%Y%m -d "2 month ago"`).
Use `date` to get year and month. Make a loop counting from 1 to (month-1).
You need to know how to get the months starting with a zero. use `printf "%02d"` for this.
Now you can do something like

```
month=1
while [ ${month} -lt $(date +%m) ]; do
   printf "$(date +%Y)%02d\n" ${month}
   ((month++))
done
```

Check what you want in month 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.I have added your code in my script.But its not working. Since   cur_yr_month="date +%Y)${month}" this is giving me the result as 20171 20172 . but I need it as 201701 201702                                                                                       month=1
ls -ltr db/files/ > file.txt
while [ ${month} -lt $(date +%m) ]; 
do
cat file.txt | while read f;
do
file_date=`echo $f | cut -d"/" -f10 | cut -d"_" -f4 | cut -d"-" -f1`
cur_yr_month="date +%Y)${month}"
if [ $cur_yr_month = $file_date ]
then
echo "$file_date"
fi
((month++))
done
done

Comment: For the additional 0 use `printf`.